# How to visualize Dirichlet distribution (with more than 3 targets)?

Tags: distributions, mathematical-statistics, data-visualization, dirichlet-distribution

I want to plot a Dirichlet distribution $\operatorname{Dir}(\alpha), \alpha=[\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \ldots,\alpha_n]$. However, when I google it, almost all of the results consider 3 targets ($n=3$), and the distribution can be visualized by a triangle (e.g. [Dirichlet distribution from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Dirichlet.pdf)).

What if I have 4 ($n=4$) or 5 ($n=5$) targets? Will the visualization be rectangle or pentagon?

To obtain some toy data, we can do

```
from scipy.stats import dirichlet
import numpy as np

n_samples = 100
alpha = np.array([0.4, 5, 15, 3, 2])
toy_data = dirichlet.rvs(alpha, size=n_samples) #shape (100, 5)
```

Answer (score 7):

A Dirichlet distribution is a distribution over a [simplex](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex).

A simplex is a lower-dimensional ($n-1)$ subspace of an $n$-dimensional space. With two targets, the simplex is a line. With three targets, it’s a triangle. In four, it’s a tetrahedron (not a square)…and so on.

The reason you don’t see 4-target examples is because it’s hard to display probability density on the 3D structure. The reason you don’t see 5-target or higher is that *we’re bad at visualizing 4D spaces*. Our visual system (and indeed, our entire grip on reality) is centered on 3D space. Trying to visualize more than that is the challenge of Abbott’s famous book *[Flatland](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flatland)*.

Comment: I've always wanted to write some code for visualizing 4-element compositional data/distributions in a tetrahedon, even though it would be more cool than useful ... I wonder if there's an analog of pairs plots for higher-order compositional data ... ??

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. It makes sense to me. If I have n=5, do you think it is reasonable to use the vertex figure (which is a pentagon) of 4-simplex to visualize the Dirichlet distribution? Or do you have any idea for visualizing 4-simplex? Thanks!

Comment: @GuanjieHuang, if you can provide an example dataset, people could play with it, & we could see what people might come up with.  Personally, I'm dying to see Ben's visualization...

Comment: @gung-ReinstateMonica Thanks! I also pretty want to see Ben's plot. BTW, I add some toy data to my question. So, each toy data will be 5D. Please feel free to let me know if you have any thought about it! Thanks